# Identify Parent Tasks

Tags: tasks, project-server, odata

I'm retrieving Tasks associated with a Project via the OData query.

```
https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=Id eq guid'xxxx'&$select=Id,Name,StartDate&$expand=Tasks
```

The above query returns all the Tasks related to the Project. Since Tasks have a hierarchical structure it was my assumption that there would be a `Parent` field on the Tasks object. How do I identify the relationship between Tasks? Is there a junction object that I need to add in `$expand`?

Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Look for the [OutlineParent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.outlineparent) property of the `Task` object.

Comment: @RachelHettinger do you mean `$expand=Tasks&$select=Tasks/Id,Tasks/OutlineParent` if yes, that didn't work